# Force dot in numeric keyboard for decimal separator in WinRT Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I use TextBox for show/edit some decimal data with InputScope="Number". 
I want to get always dot in numeric keyboard regardless settings of the phone itself (it could be comma or dot regarding phone settings).
I tried in App.xaml.cs with next code but with no success (I force the culture, don't ask why):

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = culture.Name;
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
culture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
```

Everything work just fine except the fact that keyboard always shows comma as default separator (on phone with regional setting that have comma as default).

I know that I could long tap on the comma to get dot but that don't know every user.

Comment: Why not embrace the localization and have the user enter his regional format and just convert behind the scenes (just with a ValueConverter on the binding, or in the VM itself)?

Comment: Thank, but I really would like to know how to achive this on one place

Comment: Well, i don't think it is possible at all.